# Conditional patterns with automatic nodetitles

Tags: nodes, entities

I`m using automatic nodetitles module to hide and autogenerate the title of one of my content types. My question is:

Is it possible to use conditional rules to define which pattern to be used when certain conditions is met? I need the pattern to be X if a certain field in the node is present, another if not.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module also provides the ability to use PHP to construct the pattern.  Look for the check box at the bottom.

[image]

Please refer to the module's help file for more info on combining PHP and tokens for the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if its possible to bring in content from tokens in that field?

Comment: I've not done it, but, the samples in the Help file imply that it is possible.